# implement Dijkstra in C++ to find shortest path for every vertex of a directed graph

Tags: c++, dijkstra, directed-graph

I am trying to implement the Dijkstra algorithm in c++ code that find the shortest for the graph from a text file. The text file contain a matrix that represent a directed graph.
Dijkstra algorithm find the shortest path from the source vertex to every other vertices.
What i am trying to do in this c++ is used every vertex as the source. I finished the code but I am still very skeptical if my code is right or not. Can you help me analyze the code if I have done something wrong. Thank you for taking your time.

```
int minDistance(int dist[], bool sptSet[], int V)
{
// Initialize min value
int min = INT_MAX, min_index;

for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
    if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[v] <= min)
        min = dist[v], min_index = v;

return min_index;}
double  dijkstra(int vertex, int **graph, int src)
{
auto start_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
int* dist = new int[vertex];     // The output array.  dist[i] will hold the shortest
// distance from src to i

bool* sptSet = new bool[vertex]; // sptSet[i] will true if vertex i is included in shortest
// path tree or shortest distance from src to i is finalized


src = k;
// Initialize all distances as INFINITE and stpSet[] as false
for (int i = 0; i < vertex; i++)
    {
    dist[i] = INT_MAX, sptSet[i] = false;
    }

// Distance of source vertex from itself is always 0
dist[src] = 0;

// Find shortest path for all vertices
    for (int count = 0; count < vertex - 1; count++)
    {
    // Pick the minimum distance vertex from the set of vertices not
    // yet processed. u is always equal to src in first iteration.
    int u = minDistance(dist, sptSet, vertex);

    // Mark the picked vertex as processed
    sptSet[u] = true;

    // Update dist value of the adjacent vertices of the picked vertex.
    for (int v = 0; v < vertex; v++)

        // Update dist[v] only if is not in sptSet, there is an edge from 
        // u to v, and total weight of path from src to  v through u is 
        // smaller than current value of dist[v]
        if (!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v] && dist[u] != INT_MAX && dist[u] + graph[u][v] < dist[v])
        {
        dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];
        }
    }
k++;
delete[] dist;
delete[] sptSet;
}


auto end_time = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
double elapsed = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end_time - start_time).count();

return elapsed;
}
```

Comment: maybe try on http://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: and please indent your code correctly.